# how to make a selection box in java script?

Tags: java, jsp, web, javabeans

I'm very new to java and web programming, please bear with me.

In the code below, net.a is the package name, AppConstants is the class name, there is a private string called lang in the class, and I'm trying to let the user choose which value to be put on this variable.

I have two questions, first, this does not allow me to display the website, it will show an error saying exception thrown, (which, if I take away the selection, works fine).  The class is not extending ActionForm, would that be why? But overall I'm pretty confused of how to implement a selection box, I would have an array list of values to be loaded. When I tried in the sample code, it works fine, but I couldn't move this to my own class.

Also, I have to define action under another url, I'm wondering if it's possible to put in on the main page?For example, if I modified some other file and had action display under newapp/, it wouldn't work, I have to do something to make it display under newapp/hello.do

Thanks in advance!

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>

<jsp:useBean id="helloForm" scope="request" class="net.a.AppConstants" />

<html>

<body>

<html:form action="hello">

<html:select name="helloForm" property="lang">
<html:optionsCollection name="helloForm" property="languages" value="value"         label="label"/><BR>
</html:select>


<html:submit/>
</html:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you need to submit it to anywhere but there is a quick car select drop down box

```
<form>
<select name="carlist">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Bare in mind if you are submitting it to another page you will need to add to the open form tag.

```
action="somepage.jsp" method="post"
```

if you are implementing the core library and want to populate the selects with an array do something like this. Display the taglib with your other tags.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<select label="array list" array="cars" name="Car List">
    <c:forEach var="car" items="${cars}">
        <option value="${car}">
            <c:out value="${car}"/>
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```